# Thymeleaf, table in Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html

I use Thymeleaf for print items(each has 3 values) from database, my html file is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html SYSTEM "http://www.thymeleaf.org/dtd/xhtml1-strict-thymeleaf-spring4-4.dtd">
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <title>Edycja miejsca</title>
</head>
<body>

<div th:each="items : ${itemsList}">
    <div th:object="${items}">
        <p th:text="*{id}"/>
        <p th:text="*{name}"/>
        <p th:text="*{age}"/>
    </div>
    <br/>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I try to use autocomplete, actually it is good but only for local static table in javascript, I mean:

```
var gifs = [
    { value: 'Android-explosion', data: 'AE' },
    { value: 'Ben-and-Mike', data: 'BM' },
    { value: 'Book-dominos', data: 'BD' },
    { value: 'Compiler-bot', data: 'CB' },
    { value: 'Cowboy-coder', data: 'CC' },
    { value: 'Infinite-andrew', data: 'IA' }
];

$('#autocomplete').autocomplete({
    lookup: gifs
});
```

works perfectly but I want to use autocomplite for items from database. How can I use Thymeleaf for create dynamic table in javascript?

```
<script>
var table = [];
table.push[item];
</script>
```